# global var to collect scores from levels then display at the end

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, global-variables

```
var scoreTotal:String = "Global"; //in the engine but not in the package

if (currentKey is Left && leftKey) //in each level to score points to score on stage and scoreTotal
{
    score += scoreBonus;
    scoreTotal += scoreBonus;
    currentKey.active = false;
}

public var score7:int = scoreTotal;// This is in the last level to print the score
```

I get error 1120: Access of undefined property scoreTotal.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables is not a good idea, and there is no such thing in AS3.  Instead, rather create a `Score` class, which contains anything related to keeping track of the score.  Keep a single instance of this class in your main application.  Then use events and listeners to notify the application of game events that cause the score to be updated:

```
public class Score {
    private var total:int;
    private var levels:Array;

    public function addPoints ( level:int, points:int ) : void {
        total += points;
        levels[level] += points;
    }

    public function get scoreTotal() : int {
        return total;
    }

    public function getLevelScore( level:int ) : int {
        return levels[level];
    }

    public function Score(numLevels:int) : void {
        total = 0;
        levels = [];
        var i:int = -1;
        while( ++i < numLevels) levels[i] = 0;
    }
}


public class Main {
    private var score:Score = new Score( 7 );

    private var gameEngine:GameEngine;

    ....


    private function initGameScore() : void {
        gameEngine.addEventListener ( GameEvent.SCORE, onGameScore );
        gameEngine.addEventListener ( GameEvent.BONUS, onGameBonus );
    }

    private function onGameScore( ev:GameEvent ) : void {
        addPoints( ev.points );
    }

    ....
}
```

Of course, GameEvent must derive from `flash.events.Event` and contain a field `points:int`.  You dispatch those from the GameEngine, whenever anything worth scoring occurs.

The more advanced version of this, then, is to keep a hash table of events and points, and make the actual scoring (i.e. the mapping of events to points) take place independent of the GameEngine.